# SecurityStamp is not updated on password change

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

I developed an MVC 5 application that uses ASP.NET Identity with custom user store and security stamp.

The problem is that when I change the password for a user, using this call:

```
await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(identity, hashedPassword).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

the security stamp is not updated.

The security stamp is only set on user creation. I create users with:

```
await userManager.CreateAsync(identity).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

where `identity` is the ApplicationUser object.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself. It turned out that after I set the password I should call:

```
userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(id.ToString());
```

where `id` is the primary key of the user entity, which in my custom user store is an integer.

That user manager call causes the Security Stamp to be changed for the identity and immediately it call the `UpdateAsync` method of the user store to persist it to the database.

Cheers!